# How to fix "error: cannot find the flags to link with Boost unit_test_framework"

Tags: ubuntu, boost

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04. When i tried to build a project from source and i got following message. I'm new to this and can some one help me.

```
./configure
:
:
checking boost/format.hpp presence... yes
checking for boost/format.hpp... yes
checking for the toolset name used by Boost for g++... configure: WARNING: could not figure out which toolset name to use for g++

checking boost/test/unit_test.hpp usability... yes
checking boost/test/unit_test.hpp presence... yes
checking for boost/test/unit_test.hpp... yes
checking for the Boost unit_test_framework library... no
configure: error: cannot find the flags to link with Boost unit_test_framework
```

Comment: which project are you trying to build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bumped into similar error. Installing package `libboost-test-dev` fixed the error for me

Answer (score 3):

Or you can install `libboost-all-dev` instead.